# Conservation energy problem with non-point-mass and slipping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I need help approaching the following problem I made up:

> A ***non**-point-like* block starts from rest at the top of a curved, friction-less hill.  The hill's shape -- assume 2D for simplicity -- is given by $h(x)$ -- a function that gives the hill's height as a function of horizontal distance, $x$. The block has known inertia $I$, initial height $h_0$, known mass $m$, and no initial angular velocity $\omega_{0}=0$. It starts to fall (and thus slip). Find its speed once it reaches the bottom.

[image]

I would try to solve this problem using conservation of energy:

$$
mgh_0 = \dfrac{1}{2} mv^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} I \omega ^2.
$$

However, since the relation $v_{\text{cm}} = r \omega$ will no longer hold true due to slipping, I have no clue what to do next. I have to somehow relate the $h(x)$ function to the angular velocity -- but how, I do not know.

Comment: Without information about the *friction* this is going nowhere. But the problem seems to make no mention of it.

Comment: No friction, $\mu_k=0 $

Comment: OK. **Without friction** there's no rolling or slipping, only pure sliding. Or $\dfrac{1}{2} I \omega ^2.=0$. You need friction for rolling with slipping as friction provides the torque to get rotation going.

Comment: Since the object is not a point mass and it is rotating, it does have changing angular momentum, right?

Comment: Who says it is rotating? But if it was (that could be engineered) then $\omega$ would be $\text{constant}$ because of the zero friction. In that case you don't need to take rotational kinetic energy into account because it doesn't change. Only $\frac12 mv^2$ changes.

Comment: Is it not rotating because its orientation is changing?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579380/change-in-direction-imply-angular-acceleration

Comment: Ah, now I see what you're struggling with! The answer is NO. The object would gain KE due to the change in grav. pot. energy and, **in the case of friction**, part of the transl. KE being transformed into rot. KE. The latter phenomenon would affect $v$ of course. But NOT w/o friction.

Comment: I'm afraid your misinterpreting the answer to the question you are linking to. The rot. KE to take into is for $\vec{\omega}$ for rotation ABOUT the object's axis of rotation ONLY (not any other axis).

Comment: So does the fact that the object is rotating jot affect it’s angular velocity?

Comment: Again, you're confounding things. If an object rotates then it has angular velocity: $\omega=\frac{\text{d}\theta}{\text{d}t}$. Perhaps look up 'angular velocity'?

Comment: I’m struggling to understand why the object won’t ‘rotate’ when going down.  If its orientation changes why isn’t that rotation?

Comment: You COULD consider that rotation but you're at risk of ACCOUNTING KE twice. Exercise: take an object of mass $m$ rotating an axis at velocity $v$. Q: what is its KE?A: you can calculate it from translation or from rotation, the result is the same. But in an energy accounting problem you can only account it **ONCE**! Your reasoning would account it twice!

Comment: That makes sense.  So my question would be the criteria to determine if we include both KE and rot KE?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112971/discussion-between-user256872-and-gert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to clarify the discussion about energy balances in the comment section and chat, consider the following set-up:

[image: Rotations]

Between $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have a perfect quarter of a circle, with radius $R$.

At $t=0$ a small ball with mass $m$ is released from $\theta =0$. **Assume no friction**.

At the lowest point we have, using  conservation of energy:

$$mgR=\frac12 mv^2$$

But we could also make this calculation based on the rotation of $m$ about $O$, as follows:

$$I_O=mR^2$$
$$v=\omega R\Rightarrow \omega=\frac{v}{R}$$
$$mgR=\frac12 I_O\omega^2=\frac12 mR^2 \Big(\frac{v}{R}\Big)^2=\frac12 mv^2$$
This is not just the **same number**: **it is the same energy** and shouldn't be double counted.

---

But *if there's enough friction* between the ball and the ramp's surface, then that will cause the ball to rotate about its own CoM. That rotation has of course its own kinetic energy.

Comment: The falling object is a block, not a ball, so it will rotate around its own CoM as it falls even if there is no friction.

Comment: This answer was to further clarify the difficulty the OP had in understanding the energy balance and how to calculate. See the extensive discussion in the comments and chat.

Answer (score -1):

There can be no doubt that the (square) block undergoes a 90 degree rotation. The left side of the block ends up on the bottom. On a friction-less surface, this is caused by a normal force which has a line of action which does not pass through the center of mass. The angular velocity increases as the tangential velocity increases. If you want to assume conservation of energy (and have motion), the curving surface must be friction-less. Then if the curve approximates a circle near the bottom, the block will have an angular velocity, ω = v/r, (the same as its angular velocity about the center of the circle) for as long as it stays on the circle. That will disappear quickly when it reaches the flat surface due to an external torque caused by the normal force which shifts backward from the center of gravity. An external torque puts in the rotational energy, and then takes it out.  I'm thinking it can be ignored.

Comment: *If you want to assume conservation of energy, the curving surface must be friction-less.* Not true. If everything starts from $v=0$ and there's enough friction there will be no relative movement between the surfaces (ball and ramp) and thus energy is conserved.

Comment: See for example this famous case:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Motion_in_a_fixed_plane

Comment: I'm referring to the famous race between round objects, with rolling w/o slipping of course.

Comment: See the additions to my answer above.